# Display divs inside a loop which needs to fetch data from database

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql, laravel-5

[image: Jira]

Hi everyone i need to show a set of output like in the image(jira) by fetching data into it. Can i know how to place them in a loop and and to display separate records in the database into each div. By the way i'm doing this in laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: Server-side rendering, and Client (Browser) rending to accomplish this.

Laravel 5 provides you with the starts to both of these two options right out of the box.

**Server-side rendering:**
This will be the quickest solution for you, but inherits more load on your server.

Larvel comes with it's own templating engine called "Blade":

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Once you have this working, take a look at:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

**Client (Browser) rendering:**

This is arguably the more "modern" approach, but involves you creating an API and consuming it by the front-end.

Laravel comes with the bootstrapping for Vue 2 already installed:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend

Once you have this up and running, take a look at loops and rendering lists with Vue:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html